# how to properly configure DNS when server hosting one domain is sending mail from another?

Tags: ptr-record, txt-record

i'm trying to figure out how to properly setup TXT and PTR records in the following case:
- one domain is hosted on the server  1stdomain.com on IP 1.2.3.4
- it uses remote mail server for sending mail
- remote mail server is sending email from 2nddomain.com on IP 5.6.7.8.

Quick solution qould be to send emails from same domain which is hosted on the server, but that is not possible right now.

So, i'm interested in what should be the proper DNS configuration
Should a txt record for 1stdomain.com be v=spf1 mx a ip4:1.2.3.4/32 ~all
and ptr 
4-3-2-1.2nddomain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

PTR record should match server hostname. If your server is named '1stdomain.com' and it resolves to `1.2.3.4` then PTR record for `1.2.3.4` should be `1stdomain.com`.

Comment: Instead of matching whatever host name is set internally (ie, what resolves to 127.x), the PTR record should match whatever name the server uses to announce itself (ie, the `myhostname` setting in postfix's `main.cf`) .  For example, the hostname of my machine is node3 and the FQDN is node3.my.tld but the `/etc/mailname` and `postfix`'s `myhostname` are mail.my.tld.  The reverse dns for my IP (PTR record) points to mail.my.tld

Comment: @ivanivan, please note that my answer mentions that the server hostname is FQDN resolvable to a real IP. Setting correct hostname makes its explicit setting in mail (and any other) software configuration unnecessary in typical use cases.